# Aid in setting up a Virtual Host with Wamp in Windows Vista

Tags: wamp, virtual, host

I need some help in setting up this thing.

I followed a tutorial about setting up a virtual host in WAMP which included the following steps:

1. Opened file `httpd.conf` in folder `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.6\conf` and uncommented the last # of the following statement:

   ```
   # Virtual hosts
   #Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
   ```

   to look like this:

   ```
   # Virtual hosts
   Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
   ```
2. Opened the file `httpd-vhosts.conf` in folder `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.6\conf\extra`, deleted everything in there and replaced with these codes below:

   ```
   NameVirtualHost *:80

   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.jagerseow.servegame.com (WHICH IS A DOMAIN A REGISTERED IN NO-IP)
   ServerAlias jagerseow.servegame.com domain
   DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/MP4Public
   ErrorLog "C:/wamp/www/MP4Public/logs/error.log"
   CustomLog "C:/wamp/www/MP4Public/logs/access.log" common
   </VirtualHost>"

   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www
   ErrorLog "C:/wamp/www/logs/error.log"
   CustomLog "C:/wamp/www/logs/access.log" common
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Used Notepad to open file `hosts` in folder `C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc` on server computer; then, deleted and replaced the default codes with these codes:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 localhost
   127.0.0.1 domain
   ```
4. Restarted WAMP and waited until it turned green, which it did ...
5. Try to connect to my server page by typing domain in the browser and my web page showed up normally. However when anyone, including myself, tries to open it by typing the address (http://www.jagerseow.servegame.com), no page is loaded.

I'm running Windows Vista 32-bit. Anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change your Virtual Hosts definition to this:-

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

## must be first so the the wamp menu page loads
## and stray hacks get sent here and ignored because access 
## is only allowed from local ips (127.0.0.1 localhost ::1 )
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.jagerseow.servegame.com 
    ServerAlias jagerseow.servegame.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/MP4Public"
    # changed, dont want your logs available under your docroot directory (security)
    ErrorLog "C:/wamp/www/logs/MP4Public_error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/wamp/www/logs/MP4Public_access.log" common
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/MP4Public">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>"
```

Now you need to change your hosts file to :-

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 jagerseow.servegame.com
```

After changing this do the following, or reboot.
Run a command window `Run as Administrator` and do

```
net stop "DNS Client"
net start "DNS Client"
```

This will force a refresh of the DNS Cache and make the new domain name available on your PC.

The hosts file is loaded by windows into its DNS cache. It pre-loads urls and is a bit like a very low function DNS. So this tell the dns cache and therefore your browser etc that `jagerseow.servegame.com` is found on ip address `127.0.0.1` which is `this PC`

If you actually did want the universe to be able to see this site, I assume you do as you used `Allow from all`, you will then have to port forward port 80 on your router to the ip address of the PC running wamp. Also that PC will need a STATIC ip address so it does not change when you reboot. Help for that can be found here [PortForward.com](http://portforward.com/)